# VSCode and MPI in WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, compilation, mpi, header-files, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use MPI in a C program in Visual Studio Code on Windows. I compile and run it in WSL just fine, but VSCode warns me that it can't find `mpi.h`:

[image]

I have installed `libopenmpi-dev` in WSL and added the header directories to VSCode's settings (`.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "WSL",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed",
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                    "/usr/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Standard headers like `stdio.h` are included without problems. How can I make VSCode find `mpi.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code's [remote WSL extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) makes this problem moot. No configuration is required anymore, I installed this extension, connected to WSL, and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I opened VS Code from the WSL terminal with `code .` in the desired directory and installed the extensions "C/C++ Extension Pack" and "Remote WSL". Now it works!