# MPI with MinGW and Eclipse

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mingw-w64, eclipse-kepler, cl

My question is devided in two parts :

1. What is the best combination to execute **MPI program** in **C language**, when i searched for the necessary tools i found who work with **Visual Studio** and **MS-MPI** , and who work with **Eclipse PTP** or **Code::Blocks** and **MPICH2** **MPIOpen** so i didn't know what to choose and what are tools that are compatible which other?
2. So ive installed **OpenMPI**,**Eclipse PTP (Kepler)** and **MinGW-w64** to compile some **C** programs using MPI on windows 7 64Bits. i set all paths such as **mpicc.exe** i tried to test the Hello world program which is include with eclipse as example, i got this error:

   13:03:48 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project A ****
   Info: Internal Builder is used for build

   ### mpicc "-IC:\Program" Files "(x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-x64\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\A.o" "..\src\A.c"

The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
cl.exe in your PATH.

Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in

### one of several possible environment variables.

13:03:48 Build Finished (took 115ms)

So i searched for **cl.exe** in my computer but i didn't found it, when i looked for some solution i found that the majority who solved this **cl.exe** problem are using visual studio, which is not my case so am little bit confused i dont want to switch to **Visual Studio**, so any solution with the tools that am using ?

Comment: Eclipse Kepler is 10 releases out of date, why are you using that?

Comment: Is there any eclipse release wich work with parallel programing, because i just found Kepler on their official website

Answer (score 0):

OpenMPI does not appear to officially support MinGW as a backend: https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/ms-windows.php

> The installers were configured with CMake 2.8.1 and compiled under Visual Studio 2010, and they support for C/C++ compilers of Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010.

https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/windows_coding.html and other sources found on a search describe workflows using MS-MPI with MinGW.  It may be a viable alternative.  [VSCode and MPI in WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810970/vscode-and-mpi-in-wsl) describes yet another non-paid but proprietary approach using VSCode with the WSL plugin.